# spatstat::plot.envelope observed line longer than shading

Tags: r, simulation, spatial, point-process, spatstat

Using the R package `spatstat` I'm plotting pooled pointwise envelopes of the function Jfox calculated for different point pattern in an hyperframe.

The workflow is as follow:

```
# define distances to make envelopes comparables
ers<-seq(from=0,to=3, by=0.01) 

# calculate the envelopes for the Jfox function for each point pattern in an hyperframe
urc_hyp$env_Jfox<-with(urc_hyp, envelope(Y=urc_ppp,  fun=Jfox, funargs=list(Y=pref_im), r=ers,nsim=39, fix.n=T,savefuns=TRUE, global=FALSE, nrank=1, correction='best', eps=0.1)

# split the hyperframe according to a factor
env_split<-split(urc_hyp$env_Jfox, urc_hyp$matrix)
# pool the envelopes for patterns splitted by factor
env_pool <- anylapply(env_split, FUN= pool)
```

You can find the `env_pool` object [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wytxe5evnqk42u9/AAAnV-SQv0LCB6x8M27A8r0oa?dl=0).
I can see that each envelope has an attribute of suggested *(r)* values:

```
env_pool[[1]]
```

```
Pointwise critical envelopes for J[fox](r)
and observed value for ‘urc_ppp’
Obtained from 78 simulations of CSR with fixed number of points
Alternative: two.sided
Significance level of pointwise Monte Carlo test: 2/79 = 0.0253
..................................................................................
     Math.label             Description                                           
r    r                      distance argument r                                   
obs  {hat(J)[fox]^{obs}}(r) observed value of J[fox](r) for data pattern          
theo {J[fox]^{theo}}(r)     theoretical value of J[fox](r) for CSR                
lo   {hat(J)[fox]^{lo}}(r)  lower pointwise envelope of J[fox](r) from simulations
hi   {hat(J)[fox]^{hi}}(r)  upper pointwise envelope of J[fox](r) from simulations
..................................................................................
Default plot formula:  .~r
where “.” stands for ‘obs’, ‘theo’, ‘hi’, ‘lo’
Columns ‘lo’ and ‘hi’ will be plotted as shading (by default)
Recommended range of argument r: [0, 0.46]
Available range of argument r: [0, 3]
```

So here, for example, the recomended rance goes from 0 to 0.46, while the available range is up to 3 (which is the limit I set to all the envelopes to make them comprable).

Now if I plot without specifying the range of the x axis, the plot function use by default the recomended range:

```
 plot(env_pool[[1]])
```

[image]

but If I specify the xlim I get this:

```
 plot(env_pool[[1]], xlim=c(0,3) )
```

[image]

Now, in the last figure you can see that the shaded area (which represents the significant band, as per `?envelope`) extend beyond the recomended range for *r*.

However the shading does not extend to the whole length of the black line (i.e. the observed JFox curve).

In some case the shading falls short even within the recommended *r* range (e.g. `plot(env_pool[[2]]`)

Is there theoretical a reason for this and if so how should I interpret the line after the shading?

Or is it due to some plotting parameter that should be modified/specified?

Comment: Please explain what is being plotted here.

Comment: @whuber I edited the question and explained in details the workflow that resulted in the plot. can you( or I) reopen the question?

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is correct. The shaded region is the envelope of 39 curves which were each computed by generating a completely random pattern and computing the estimate of Foxall's J function `Jfox` for the pattern. The J functions are ratios of survival functions, `J(r) = (1-G(r))/(1-F(r))` where F and G are estimates of the cumulative distribution functions of certain distances in the point pattern. The estimate of `J(r)` is obviously undefined if the estimate of `F(r)` is zero. When that happens, the estimate of `J(r)` is returned by `Jfox` as `NA` or `NaN`. The `envelope` function discards any such values when determining the envelope. A value of `NA` or `NaN` in the envelope at a certain value of `r` means that **all** of the simulated J function values were `NA` or `NaN`. That is, out of 39 random point patterns, **none** of the point patterns had an empty-space distance greater than this distance `r`. The data point pattern is different from the random patterns in that it apparently has some very large empty-space distances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone so can't check any details, but my best guess is that the upper bound of the envelope (`hi`) is `NA` when the shading stops. You can use `as.data.frame` to convert the envelope to a `data.frame` and inspect the values. This may be a mathematical problem with the estimator and not a computational problem / bug, but I can't investigate right now.

Comment: It does indeed shows `NA` (in some instances `NaN`) values both for `hi` and `low` columns